# What does this statement mean?

Tags: spoken-english

[image]

"....that refused to turne Moretto's [Marathas] of his own persuasion.."

I'm not able to understand the structure and meaning of these words. Help me understand this statement.

Comment: Yes, when I realized the error, I removed my comment, it seems as you were typing.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Ah, I see.

Answer (score 1):

It means that Sevagee cut off the heads of four padres who refused to become/convert into *Moretto's* (Marathas-Hindus). The **of his owne persuasion** part is a little harder to interpret but I think it means that these four padres refused to convert into *Moretto's* **even after Sevagee had tried to persuade or convince them to**. So *his owne persuasion* in that sentence means Sevagee's efforts to convince the Padres.

Edit: After seeing Tᴚoɯɐuo's comment, I now think that **of his owne persuasion** means Sevagee's religious beliefs. He was trying to convert the padres to his beliefs.

Comment: I read  **persuasion** as "religious beliefs".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo That's a good point. It could be that Sevagee was trying to convert the padres to his own beliefs

Comment: The interpretation would hinge on whether we take **turne** to be  transitive (convert others) or intransitive (become oneself). I think intransitive works best, if Sevagee was himself of Marathas persuasion.  **they** in *they having councelled the destruction* refers to the padres.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo From the little I have just read of this bit of history, the padres were christians who were terrorizing the Hindus so Sevagee cut their heads off. But before he did, he gave them the chance to become Hindus, which they refused. So with that context, I'm pretty sure it's intransitive in this case. It would be difficult to say otherwise.

Comment: @phil14 Actually, these Padres had ordered to kill non-christians in his territory. So Maratha King tried to persuade their minds to put halt on these orders but they refused.